# Visualizing time spans on a timeline as a horizontal histogram / bar chart

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

I have a csv table of 6 events and the time span of their occurrence. My variables are begin date, end date, and event-ID. I intend to create a horizontal histogram / bar chart visualization that displays the time range i.e. how long certain types of events lasted. The X-axis should have the dates ranging over a number of years, and the Y-Axis should have the different kinds of event ID's. Ideally, I want horizontal bars in the length of the time spans. One event has more than one time span. The event begins, then ends. After a few months it begins, lasts for some time and ends again. I have about 6 event-IDs that have many different occurrences. I just want to see the occurrances on a timeline to have an overview...

Edit:
the table looks something like this:

```
Begin      End          EventID
01.01.2000 01.05.2000   Chicago
03.04.1998 03.09.1999   New York
12.03.2014 16.07.2014   Los Angeles
12.12.2003 03.06.2004   Amsterdam
21.06.1993 14.12.1993   Paris
27.02.1995 15.03.1995   London
14.06.2002 15.06.2002   Madrid
```

I tried the following code:

```
cities <- read.table(textConnection("Begin End EventID
01.01.2000 01.05.2000   Chicago
03.04.1998 03.09.1999   New York
12.03.2014 16.07.2014   Los Angeles
12.12.2003 03.06.2004   Amsterdam
21.06.1993 14.12.1993   Paris
27.02.1995 15.03.1995   London
14.06.2002 15.06.2002   Madrid
"), sep=" ", header=TRUE)

cities$Begin<- as.Date(cities$Begin, "%d.%m.%Y")
cities$End<- as.Date(cities$End, "%d.%m.%Y")
cities$EventID<- as.factor(cities$EvenID)
cities$Sep <- as.factor(1:length(cities$Begin))

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=cities) + geom_segment(aes(x=Begin, xend=End, y=EventID, yend=EventID, 
group=Sep), size=12)
```

For:

```
cities$EventID<- as.factor(cities$EvenID)
```

I get an error message, because EventID does not contain integers.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "EventID", value = integer(0)) : 
Replacement has 0 rows. Data has 75
```

Do I have to convert the data in EventID  into something else? And if so, what is it?

Comment: This code is not reproducible, the city names have spaces, so will not read in using a space as the seperator. The specific code `cities$EventID<- as.factor(cities$EvenID)` is simply a typo for `EvenID` should be `EventID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you want using the `ggplot2` package. The grammer makes this chart somewhat easy to construct (it takes much more code to replicate your data!)

```
Lines <- read.table(textConnection("Begin End EventID
01.01.2000 01.05.2000 1
03.04.1998 03.09.1999 1
12.03.2014 16.07.2014 2
12.12.2003 03.06.2004 3
21.06.1993 14.12.1993 2
27.02.1995 15.03.1995 3
14.06.2002 15.06.2002 2
"), sep=" ", header=TRUE)

Lines$Begin <- as.Date(Lines$Begin, "%d.%m.%Y")
Lines$End <- as.Date(Lines$End, "%d.%m.%Y")
Lines$EventID <- as.factor(Lines$EventID)
Lines$Sep <- as.factor(1:length(Lines$Begin))

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=Lines) + 
     geom_segment(aes(x = Begin, xend = End, y = EventID, yend = EventID, group=Sep)
     ,size =12)
p
```

[image]

Your description of a histogram of intervals reminds me of [this](http://nxn.se/post/54932205980/visualizing-overlapping-intervals), but that does not seem to be what you are asking about.

---

With your updated code, it is simply typos that are causing the problems. Here is an example with your new data (amended the `read.table` to work and a typo in converting `EventID` to a factor).

Here I also sorted the plot based on the earliest date at the top. Note you actually do not need the `Sep` grouping variable in this example, as you do not have multiple time spans for the same city.

```
cities <- read.table(textConnection("Begin End EventID
01.01.2000 01.05.2000 Chicago
03.04.1998 03.09.1999 New_York
12.03.2014 16.07.2014 Los_Angeles
12.12.2003 03.06.2004 Amsterdam
21.06.1993 14.12.1993 Paris
27.02.1995 15.03.1995 London
14.06.2002 15.06.2002 Madrid
"), sep=" ", header=TRUE)

cities$Begin <- as.Date(cities$Begin, "%d.%m.%Y")
cities$End <- as.Date(cities$End, "%d.%m.%Y")
cities$EventID <- gsub("_"," ",cities$EventID)
cities$EventID <- as.factor(cities$EventID)
cities$Sep <- as.factor(1:length(cities$Begin))

#sorting levels so earliest is at top of graph
cities <- transform(cities, EventID=reorder(EventID, -rank(Begin)))

p <- ggplot(data=cities) + 
     geom_segment(aes(x=Begin, xend=End, y=EventID, yend=EventID, group=Sep), size=12)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Pen and paper probably would have been faster!

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. And you guessed correctly, the "histogram" I was talking about was exactly the link you posted. Thanks again for your help, I will try this out!

Comment: Just one more question Andy, what do I convert the event ID into if the IDs are actually written in letters, i.e. they are Names (for the sake of the above example I used numbers but theyre actually names) ?

Comment: @AC11 it doesn't matter for constructing the chart. Just make sure they are factor variables and ggplot2 will construct the appropriate axis labels.

Comment: Okay, I just used as.factor for Event ID's although they are Strings. The time slots were not painted into the ggplot, but I got 'warnings' for each observation saying: "Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment)." What could that be? I am assuming its because of the Event ID conversion

Comment: I think R thinks that each row contains NAs

Comment: Not sure, you will need to create a reproducible example for me to be able to give any good advice. Are the date-times actually coded as dates and not factors or strings? Also make sure to have the grouping variable like I made (called `Sep` in my code).

Comment: Disregad the comment about the 'warnings aboout NA's' because that was due to an unrelated mistake. I just edited my original post to give you a reproducable example about what is happening!

Comment: This worked! I really did make so many little mistakes.. Thank you so much Andy!